# How do I get a Halo component and change its color?

Tags: unity

I have a Halo component on an object, on the same object I have a script, in the script I tried to get the Halo component, but `GetComponent<Halo>()` doesn't work, it says that it can't be found.

My question is, how can I get the Halo component and change the color of it?

Comment: how exactly are you calling GetComponent. Can you share the code? Its pretty hard yo help you without any code.

Comment: Ok I'll modify my question now

Comment: greenPadawan's code should work for you. The problem is you are trying to use Halo as its own Type, while in reality its Type is a Behaviour.

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of the Halo?

Comment: I dont think you change the color from script of a Halo component. But if you use a Light with the Draw Halo option checked. Then you can change the light color and  the halo will change too.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on internet and it did work for me...

**warning: Tested only in unity editor...**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ChangeHalo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private bool _isEnabled = true;
    [SerializeField] private Color _color = Color.red;
    [SerializeField] private float _size = 1;


    private void Update()
    {
        SerializedObject halo = new SerializedObject(GetComponent("Halo"));
        halo.FindProperty("m_Size").floatValue = _size;
        halo.FindProperty("m_Enabled").boolValue = _isEnabled;
        halo.FindProperty("m_Color").colorValue = _color;
        halo.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

**Thanks to this person: https://answers.unity.com/users/656364/hyper00.html**
Cheers!

Comment: Works well, but only in editor.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Halo component you must do as follows.

```
Behaviour halo =(Behaviour)gameObject.GetComponent ("Halo");
```

Comment: That seems to work but how would I get the color of it?

Comment: Halo is a built-in component that isn't exposed to scripting. A problem similar to that of yours has already been discussed in the unity forum. See the following [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10534/changing-color-of-halo.html). I would suggest if you have to change the color, you can use a light instead of a halo.